# Using Bootrstrap in Bitrix24 CRM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, crm, bootstrap-5, bitrix

I'm pretty new to Bitrix24 (On-premise) and I am trying to use Bootstrap on several pages.

It's an existing project, and I'm trying to renew page for page, to get some more structure into it.
Is it possible to use Bootstrap for single pages like: `yourdomain/compliance/` in my case?

I tried to create a new page template, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer myself.

For your interest: Download CSS/JS files from Bootstrap, select your current Bitrix-Template and upload the files into the folder. Require the new files like:

```
$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/pathtocss/your.css", true);
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/pathtojs/yourjs.js", true);
```

Remember to use the correrct paths.